# How do I add onChange events to a list of elements, that will update the HTML with current values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, addeventlistener, dom-events

I want to (programmatically, of course) add an event listener to a list (array of objects) of HTML input fields that will fire a change event but provide the value that is currently in the input and not what was in the input fields at the time the function that does the adding of events, runs.

After trying to capture the input fields as late as possible, I still get the default values of the form and not the current values returned.
At least the intended input fields do indeed have a change event listener attached, so I'm half way there... >.>

```
// only sets events with values at time of execution!
function setEvents() {
    let fieldList = [{"fld": "saleDate","type": "date"},{"fld": "pickupDate","type": "date"},{"fld": "deposit","type": "cash"}];

    for(let pair of fieldList) {
        $('#' + pair['fld']).bind('change',
            {k: pair['fld'], v: $('#' + pair['fld']).val(), t: pair['type']},
            function (event) {
                let tKey = "", tVal = "", tDate = new Date();
                switch (event.data.t) {
                    case "date":
                        tKey = event.data.k;
                        tDate = new Date(event.data.v);
                        tVal = tDate.toLocaleDateString('en-GB');
                        break;
                    default:
                        tKey = event.data.k;
                        tVal = event.data.v;
                }
                addItem(tKey, tVal);
            });
    }
}

// this function works but is HEAVILY trimmed so you can see what I'm doing with the variables
function addItem (key, val) {
    var tmpItem = document.createElement("LI");
    var tmpNode = document.createTextNode(key.toUpperCase() + ": " + val);
    tmpItem.appendChild(tmpNode);
    tmpItem.setAttribute("name", key);
    getElementById("summaryList").box.appendChild(tmpItem);
}
```

Like said above, the change event is being added to the elements as expected.
I have alerts that tell me that the same value is being passed with each event trigger. aka the default values of the form.

Comment: Where is your event listener?

Comment: The event listener should use `this.value` to get the value of the input at the time the event occurs.

Comment: Oh, you're using jQuery `bind`, not `addEventListener`. `bind` is deprecated, you should use `on`.

Answer (score 0):

Get the value in the event listener function, not when binding.

In the event listener, `this` is the event target, and `this.value` is the value of the element.

```
for (let pair of fieldList) {
  $('#' + pair['fld']).on('change', {
      k: pair['fld'],
      t: pair['type']
    },
    function(event) {
      let tKey = "",
        tVal = "",
        tDate = new Date();
      switch (event.data.t) {
        case "date":
          tKey = event.data.k;
          tDate = new Date(this.value);
          tVal = tDate.toLocaleDateString('en-GB');
          break;
        default:
          tKey = event.data.k;
          tVal = this.value;
      }
      addItem(tKey, tVal);
    });
}
```

Comment: yeah I spotted it. didn't think I could use ```this``` like that tho. worried about scope.

Comment: Isn't it the most common way to write event handlers in jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't do it late enough!!!

I knew that I had to have the code that adds the event be the location that grabs the current value from the form elements, like this;

```
function setEvents() {
    let fieldList = [
        {
            "fld": "saleDate",
            "type": "date"
        },
        {
            "fld": "pickupDate",
            "type": "date"
        },
        {
            "fld": "deposit",
            "type": "cash"
        }
    ],
    tKey = "", tVal = "", tDate = new Date();

    // begin loop through JSON of elements
    for(let pair of fieldList) {
        // add change event listener but don't get element value yet!
        $('#' + pair['fld']).bind('change',
            {k: pair['fld'], t: pair['type']},
            function (event) {
                // in here is where I should get current form values!
                let tKey = "", tVal = "", tDate = new Date();

                switch (event.data.t) {
                    case "date":
                        tKey = event.data.k;
                        // this grabs fresh data from the form!
                        tDate = new Date($('#' + event.data.k).val());
                        tVal = tDate.toLocaleDateString('en-GB');

                        break;
                    default:
                        tKey = event.data.k;
                        // and so does this!!
                        tVal = $('#' + event.data.k).val();
                }

                updateSummary(tKey, tVal);
            });
    }
}
```

Thanks for the fresh pair of eyes!

Comment: `$('#' + event.data.k)` is the same as `$(this)` when you're in the listener. No need to search the DOM for the ID when you have a direct reference to the element.